# parse the xml to find the root tag and then append the tags under the root tag

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have a *xml* file in my web-directory . Currently it looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Blobs>

</Blobs>
```

I want to dynamically add a tag *blobkey* under the tag *Blob*. If a tag has been added , next time the new tag should be appended. How do I do this ? First I need to parse the xml file,to find the root element and then append a new tag named *blobkey* under the tag *Blobs* which is the root tag.

This was some code that I wrote for this,but it doesn't suit my requirements.Please suggest something.

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();            
        Document document = db.newDocument();

        Element blobKey_E = document.createElement("BlobKey");
        blobKey_E.appendChild( document.createTextNode( blobKey ) );
        // Save the xml file after this
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getDocumentElement().appendChild(blobKey_E)`